# Quelles règles gouvernent l'usage de « en quoi » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, en

Je sais comment utiliser les pronoms relatifs « ce à quoi », « de quoi », etc., et je pense que quand je dis les choses comme

> En quoi puis-je vous aider ?

> Je ne vois pas en quoi c'est compliqué !

> En quoi ça consiste ?

que je le suis les règles, par contre je n'arrive pas à mettre la main dessus. C'est-à-dire, concrètement, quelles sont les règles qui nous disent quand et comment utiliser le pronom relatif « en quoi ». En particulier, est-ce qu'il s'agit d'une expression ou d'expressions fixe(s) ?

Comment: « D'une expression ou d'expressions fixe(s) » : Du point de vue de la langue parlée, voilà de la langue « morte ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I** Il ne s'agit pas du tout d'une expression fixe ; c'est à dire que l'on considère que « quoi » est le complément de la  préposition « en » (régime de « en »).

On utilise cette construction pour les verbes  ou locutions verbales dont la préposition est « en », mais on préfère parfois d’autres tournures parce que l’utilisation de « en quoi » ne semble pas toujours très idiomatique.

*Cas de « consister en »*

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consister)) **B.** − [Le suj. désigne une chose divisible, considérée dans ses parties constitutives] Être formé, constitué par (certains éléments). Synon. comporter, se composer (de), comprendre. Sa dot consiste en immeubles. La cargaison consiste en bananes, cocos et agrumes
> •Le dîner, celui du patron d'ailleurs, **consistait** en un gros plat de viande, un plat de légumes, et une salade. Balzac, Un Début dans la vie,1842, p. 437.
> **Rem.**  Dans ce cas *consister* se construit avec *en* suivi d'un subst. seul ou avec un art. (sauf l'art. déf.), un adj. poss., dém., etc.
> • Le bétail consiste en vaches, moutons et chèvres;
> • son bagage consiste en trois malles;
> • le mobilier consistait en une table. Synon. réduire (se réduire à...).

Le pronom « quoi » (choses) est seulement l’une de deux possibilités, l’autre étant « qui » (personne).

- Il ne sait pas **en qui** avoir confiance. (*avoir confiance **en***)
- Ce n’était pas quelqu’un **en qui** on pouvait croire. (*croire **en** qqu*)
- (*pas très idiomatique*) Nous dire **en quoi** il parle ne nous explique pas ce qu’il dit. (*parler **en** qqc (latin, anglais, allemand,…)*)
- (*préférable*) Nous dire quelle langue  il parle ne nous explique pas ce qu’il dit.
- En/Dans quoi sont-ils arrivés à la perfection ?  (*arriver à la perfection **en/dans**  qqc*)
- Elle est calée en agronomie. En quoi est-elle calée ?  (*être calé **en** qqc*, familier)

**II** Dans ces deux  contextes on peut considérer que « en quoi » prend une valeur idiomatique (expression fixe) en cela que l'on ne peut pas analyser la particule « en » comme ayant un rapport défini avec le verbe.

> **A** En quoi puis-je vous [aider/ être utile/dépanner/… ?

Ce cas d’utilisation se détache du schéma expliqué au « **I** », en cela que le complément circonstanciel peut être introduit par diverses prépositions ou qu'il peut être remplacé par un gérondif.

> - Vous pouvez m'aider **à** faire le ménage.
> - Vous pouvez m'aider **dans** les travaux ménagers.
> - Vous pouvez m'aider **en** vous chargeant des tâches pénibles.

La valeur de « en quoi » est adverbiale, proche de « comment ».¹

> **B** Je ne vois pas en quoi c'est compliqué !

La préposition (ou locution prépositive) utilisable peut être l'une d'un choix varié, ou bien une conjonction peut la remplacer dans une construction avec une subordonnée.

> - C'est compliqué **du fait de** la multitude des détails qu'il faut connaitre. (*locution prépositive*)
> - C'est compliqué **par** la multitude des détails qui contribuent à la compréhension.
> - C'est compliqué **en raison de** la multitude de détails à apprendre.
> - C'est compliqué **parce qu**'il y a beaucoup de détails. (*conjonction*)

La valeur de « en quoi » serait encore adverbiale, proche de « pourquoi ».¹

<sub>**Note**  *pas de référence pour cette affirmation, qui n'est que mon opinion*</sub>

Comment: Franchement, on ne te mérite pas @LPH, cette réponse est incroyable. Merci !